# How to set the constraints for this modalVC layout correctly?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am having trouble setting the constraints correctly for one of my viewcontrollers. It's a modal viewController and for now I have a full main background UIView constraint to all 4 edges of the device. Then on top of that I have another UIView on top which have one textview and two buttons and one label.

Here are the constraints:

1. main background(covering the full screen size)

[image]

2. A UIView over that main background (blue color)

[image]
[image]

3. textview constraints:

[image]
[image]

4. done button:

[image]
[image]

5. cancel button:

[image]
[image]

6. Edit Task label:

[image]
[image]

Views hierarchy:

[image]

This is what I am getting when I run the app on 8 Plus with "View as: " option as iPhone 8:

[image]